# Only int128 and uint256 int types in vyper

Tags: vyper

I have read vyper documentation and there is something strange: I only see uint256 and int128 data types for integer values.

There is no way to create an uint8 for example in vyper ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Nope, there are no uint/int types in recent vyper versions except uint256 and int128</strike>

There used to be in the early beta releases I believe, but they were removed since, check out this for some older release notes involving changes to int128

Vyper has auditability, security, and readability as it's priorities and decided it was easier to understand contracts when there are only two integer types rather than a slew of them

EDIT: there is now support for arbitrary sized signed and unsigned integers in vyper (v0.3.9 being the latest as of this writing)

> intN 
> A signed integer which can store positive and negative integers. N must be a multiple of 8 between 8 and 256 (inclusive).

> uintN 
> A unsigned integer which can store positive integers. N must be a multiple of 8 between 8 and 256 (inclusive).

For uint: https://docs.vyperlang.org/en/stable/types.html#unsigned-integer-n-bit 
For int: https://docs.vyperlang.org/en/stable/types.html#signed-integer-n-bit